# How to fix TCPIP server/clinet apps communication

Tags: c#, tcp

I need to make TCPIP server and client apps which will communicate and do some sending of random files. So far, I made this:

Server:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     IPAddress localIP = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
     TcpListener tcpServerListener = new TcpListener(localIP, 1234);
     tcpServerListener.Start();
     Console.WriteLine("Service started...");
     while (true)
     {
        var serverSocket = tcpServerListener.AcceptTcpClient();
        Console.WriteLine("Request accepted!");
        if (serverSocket.Connected)
        {
            Do(serverSocket);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Waiting for new request...");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

private static void Do(TcpClient serverSocket)
{
    var serverSockStream = serverSocket.GetStream();
    var reader = new StreamReader(serverSockStream);
    var poruka = reader.ReadLine();
    var odgovor = "Hello " + poruka;
    var writer = new StreamWriter(serverSockStream);
    writer.Flush();
    reader.Close();
    writer.Close();
}
```

Client:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 1234);
    NetworkStream clientSockStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
    var writer = new StreamWriter(clientSockStream);
    writer.WriteLine("TCP/IP Client");
    writer.Flush();
    var reader = new StreamReader(clientSockStream);
    var odgovor = reader.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Answer received: " + odgovor);
    writer.Close();
    reader.Close();
}
```

The problem I am facing is that once I achieve communication, the second response crashes:

> Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted

So, how to fix this error and later allow sending files? (later with serialization etc.)

Comment: There is this article about port exhaustion. Don't be misled by the fact that it's a Biztalk article, there is some cool info on how to diagnose the problem: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560610(v=bts.20).aspx

Comment: Are you sure you're not trying to launch the server multiple times? Unlike the client, it never exits (and the `Console.ReadLine` just prevents you from receiving another client until you press enter, not sure why you'd want to do that). Anyway, TCP is quite hard to get right. Are you sure you don't want to use something that already works? If yes, make sure to learn the way TCP works first, and learn what problems you can see in practice and how to handle all the various states and error scenarios.

Comment: Can you answer separately to flag your answer as correct, because you solved my problem with communication?  Thanks. @Luaan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you're not trying to launch the server multiple times? Unlike the client, the server never exits and the `Console.ReadLine` prevents you from receiving another client until you press enter. I assume the old server is still hung in the background while you try to launch a new one, which necessarily fails. Get rid of the `ReadLine`, add a proper way to exit the server, and don't run multiple servers at the same time, and you should be fine.

Writing a custom TCP client/server application is very tricky. TCP is still a very low-level protocol, and it likely doesn't work the way you expect it to. If you choose to follow this path, make sure to learn how TCP works first, and learn how to properly handle all the communication states and errors.

Answer (score 1):

Friend, you seem to be re-inventing the wheel here.  With all the technologies available to do this, there's no reason why you need to be doing this stuff at the "sockets" level.  Far more simpler:

- Use an FTP server on one end, and the FTP client built-in to .NET
- Write a web service with a method that allows a calling client to send a stream.

Anything but sockets.  You'll waste a lot of time.

Comment: I know, but this is my task. I know that there is a huge span of possibilities, but I need to do this. @codenoire

Comment: A web service is, in fact, a TCP server.